# How check :new value in compound triggers, when after statement is specified?

Tags: oracle, triggers

I have a problem with compound trigger. :new.value is blank/empty in a *before each row* part when an *after* part is specified.

create table part:

```
  DROP TABLE test_tab;
  CREATE TABLE test_tab
    ( ID_TEST_TAB NUMBER
    );
  INSERT INTO test_tab VALUES
    (1
    );
  INSERT INTO test_tab VALUES
    (2
    );
```

trigger's part:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER TEST_COMP_TRIGGER
  FOR UPDATE ON test_tab
  COMPOUND TRIGGER   
---
BEFORE EACH ROW
IS
BEGIN
  dbms_output.put_line('TEST_COMP_TRIGGER:  BEFORE EACH ROW');
  dbms_output.put_line('>>>> old: ' || :old.ID_TEST_TAB );
  dbms_output.put_line('>>>> new: ' || :new.ID_TEST_TAB );
  NULL;
END BEFORE EACH ROW;
---
AFTER STATEMENT
IS
BEGIN
  NULL;
END AFTER STATEMENT;
END TEST_COMP_TRIGGER;
/
```

after:

```
UPDATE test_tab SET test_tab.ID_TEST_TAB=test_tab.ID_TEST_TAB;
```

I get:

```
TEST_COMP_TRIGGER:  BEFORE EACH ROW
>>>> old: 1
>>>> new: 
TEST_COMP_TRIGGER:  BEFORE EACH ROW
>>>> old: 2
>>>> new:
```

If an *after* part is omitted, result is correct:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER TEST_COMP_TRIGGER
  FOR UPDATE ON test_tab
  COMPOUND TRIGGER
---
BEFORE EACH ROW
IS
BEGIN
  dbms_output.put_line('TEST_COMP_TRIGGER:  BEFORE EACH ROW');
  dbms_output.put_line('>>>> old: ' || :old.ID_TEST_TAB );
  dbms_output.put_line('>>>> new: ' || :new.ID_TEST_TAB );
  NULL;
END BEFORE EACH ROW;
END TEST_COMP_TRIGGER;
/
```

after:

```
UPDATE test_tab SET test_tab.ID_TEST_TAB=test_tab.ID_TEST_TAB;
```

I get:

```
TEST_COMP_TRIGGER:  BEFORE EACH ROW
>>>> old: 1
>>>> new: 2
TEST_COMP_TRIGGER:  BEFORE EACH ROW
>>>> old: 2
>>>> new: 2
```

why in first case :new.value is blank?

----------- update
I followed yours instructions:
code:

```
create or replace trigger TEST_COMP_TRIGGER
FOR UPDATE ON test_tab  
COMPOUND TRIGGER   
---- BEFORE
  BEFORE STATEMENT
  IS
  BEGIN
    dbms_output.put_line('TEST_COMP_TRIGGER:  BEFORE STATEMENT');
    NULL;
  END BEFORE STATEMENT;
---- AFTER
  AFTER STATEMENT IS
  BEGIN
    dbms_output.put_line('TEST_COMP_TRIGGER:  AFTER STATEMENT');
    NULL;
  END AFTER STATEMENT;
---- BEFORE EACH
  BEFORE EACH ROW IS
  BEGIN
    dbms_output.put_line('TEST_COMP_TRIGGER:  BEFORE EACH ROW');
    dbms_output.put_line('>>>> old: ' || :old.ID_TEST_TAB );
    dbms_output.put_line('>>>> new: ' || :new.ID_TEST_TAB );
    NULL;
  END BEFORE EACH ROW;
END TEST_COMP_TRIGGER;
/

-----
SET serveroutput ON format wraped;
UPDATE test_tab SET test_tab.ID_TEST_TAB=test_tab.ID_TEST_TAB;
/
```

gives expected result:

```
    2 rows updated.
TEST_COMP_TRIGGER:  BEFORE STATEMENT
TEST_COMP_TRIGGER:  BEFORE EACH ROW
>>>> old: 1
>>>> new: 1
TEST_COMP_TRIGGER:  BEFORE EACH ROW
>>>> old: 2
>>>> new: 2
TEST_COMP_TRIGGER:  AFTER STATEMENT
```

but when I add AFTER EACH ROW statement:

```
create or replace trigger TEST_COMP_TRIGGER
FOR UPDATE ON test_tab  
COMPOUND TRIGGER   
---- BEFORE
  BEFORE STATEMENT
  IS
  BEGIN
    dbms_output.put_line('TEST_COMP_TRIGGER:  BEFORE STATEMENT');
    NULL;
  END BEFORE STATEMENT;
---- AFTER
  AFTER STATEMENT IS
  BEGIN
    dbms_output.put_line('TEST_COMP_TRIGGER:  AFTER STATEMENT');
    NULL;
  END AFTER STATEMENT;
---- BEFORE EACH
  BEFORE EACH ROW IS
  BEGIN
    dbms_output.put_line('TEST_COMP_TRIGGER:  BEFORE EACH ROW');
    dbms_output.put_line('>>>> old: ' || :old.ID_TEST_TAB );
    dbms_output.put_line('>>>> new: ' || :new.ID_TEST_TAB );
    NULL;
  END BEFORE EACH ROW;
---- AFTER EACH  
  AFTER EACH ROW
  IS
  BEGIN
    dbms_output.put_line('TEST_COMP_TRIGGER:  AFTER EACH ROW');
  END AFTER EACH ROW;
END TEST_COMP_TRIGGER;
/

-----
SET serveroutput ON format wraped;
UPDATE test_tab SET test_tab.ID_TEST_TAB=test_tab.ID_TEST_TAB;
/
```

I'm still getting empty :new:

```
2 rows updated.
TEST_COMP_TRIGGER:  BEFORE STATEMENT
TEST_COMP_TRIGGER:  BEFORE EACH ROW
>>>> old: 1
>>>> new: 
TEST_COMP_TRIGGER:  AFTER EACH ROW
TEST_COMP_TRIGGER:  BEFORE EACH ROW
>>>> old: 2
>>>> new: 
TEST_COMP_TRIGGER:  AFTER EACH ROW
TEST_COMP_TRIGGER:  AFTER STATEMENT
```

Comment: What version of Oracle are you using?

Comment: Oracle Database 11g Enterprise Edition Release 11.2.0.1.0 - 64bit Production, 
PL/SQL Release 11.2.0.1.0 - Production

Answer (score 0):

The order of the  timing-point sections matters and needs to be:

```
BEFORE STATEMENT
AFTER STATEMENT
BEFORE EACH ROW
AFTER EACH ROW
```

Ref: [Compound Trigger Sections, Oracle 11gR1 docs](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/appdev.111/b28370/triggers.htm#CIHJBEFE)

The following script (run in Oracle SQL Developer connected to `Oracle Database 11g Express Edition Release 11.2.0.2.0 - Production`

```
DROP TABLE test_tab;
CREATE TABLE test_tab ( ID_TEST_TAB NUMBER);
INSERT INTO test_tab VALUES (1);
INSERT INTO test_tab VALUES (2);

create or replace trigger TEST_COMP_TRIGGER
FOR UPDATE ON test_tab  
COMPOUND TRIGGER   

  AFTER STATEMENT IS
  BEGIN
    dbms_output.put_line('TEST_COMP_TRIGGER:  AFTER STATEMENT');
    NULL;
  END AFTER STATEMENT;

  BEFORE EACH ROW IS
  BEGIN
    dbms_output.put_line('TEST_COMP_TRIGGER:  BEFORE EACH ROW');
    dbms_output.put_line('>>>> old: ' || :old.ID_TEST_TAB );
    dbms_output.put_line('>>>> new: ' || :new.ID_TEST_TAB );
    NULL;
  END BEFORE EACH ROW;

END TEST_COMP_TRIGGER;
/

set serveroutput on format wraped;
UPDATE test_tab SET test_tab.ID_TEST_TAB=test_tab.ID_TEST_TAB+1;
/
```

Produces as output:

```
table TEST_TAB dropped.
table TEST_TAB created.
1 rows inserted.
1 rows inserted.
TRIGGER TEST_COMP_TRIGGER compiled
2 rows updated.
TEST_COMP_TRIGGER:  BEFORE EACH ROW
>>>> old: 1
>>>> new: 2
TEST_COMP_TRIGGER:  BEFORE EACH ROW
>>>> old: 2
>>>> new: 3
TEST_COMP_TRIGGER:  AFTER STATEMENT
```

Swapping them into the wrong order the output ends up as:

```
table TEST_TAB dropped.
table TEST_TAB created.
1 rows inserted.
1 rows inserted.
TRIGGER TEST_COMP_TRIGGER compiled
2 rows updated.
TEST_COMP_TRIGGER:  BEFORE EACH ROW
>>>> old: 1
>>>> new: 
TEST_COMP_TRIGGER:  BEFORE EACH ROW
>>>> old: 2
>>>> new: 
TEST_COMP_TRIGGER:  AFTER STATEMENT
```

Comment: I found table you metioned: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/appdev.111/b28370/triggers.htm#g4897004 but why example Example 9-2 Compound Trigger
 has different order? I tried change order but I'm still getting the same output:

Comment: Odd the example doesn't follow the instructions listed about order. When tested here using the order in the table the desired results were produced (showed both before and after values).

Comment: @Brian: Although the order you gave is how they're printed in the documentation, the actual order of section firing is BEFORE STATEMENT, BEFORE EACH ROW, AFTER EACH ROW, AFTER STATEMENT.  You might want to write a little test to demonstrate this to yourself, and then edit your post appropriately.  Share and enjoy.

Comment: @Bob_Jarvis: The order they must appear in the source isn't the same as the order they are executed in.

Comment: AFAIK they are not required to appear in any particular order in the source code.  I've got a test trigger here, ordered as BEFORE STATEMENT, BEFORE EACH ROW, AFTER EACH ROW, AFTER STATEMENT.  For fun I just created a second trigger and completely reversed the above order in the source code.  Both compiled and executed fine.  I suggest you test this yourself and edit your answer appropriately.  Thanks.

Comment: @Bob_Jarvis: Perhaps it only fails when some sections are missing. Your original example and problem show it fails when just AFTER STATEMENT and BEFORE EACH ROW are in an order different than listed in the table.

Comment: @Brian: I've now created five different compound triggers on my test table.  All have trigger points ordered differently.  Some have all the trigger points, others have only some (including the two you stated, AFTER STATEMENT, and BEFORE EACH ROW).  All compile and execute properly, and in the firing point order I mentioned.  I think you've read more into the docs than is there - Oracle states *what* the trigger points are but does not say anything about required order in the source.  I really think you need to go back and do some testing of this issue, then revise your response.  Thanks.

Comment: From the reference: A compound trigger defined on a table has one or more of the timing-point sections described in Table 9-1. Timing-point sections must appear in the order shown in Table 9-1. If a timing-point section is absent, nothing happens at its timing point.

Comment: I followed yours advices. @Brian - script from your first resposne works correctly, but when I add after each row statement, result is unexpected - I've updated my question with script. Could you try my second scripts and check results on yours instances?

Comment: I get the same blank NEW as you. However if the AFTER EACH ROW includes the bind variables then NEW contains the correct values in BEFORE EACH ROW as well.

Comment: It's a bug or a feature? I didn't find anything about this in documentation.

Comment: Buggy and poor documentation (text says order matters, example doesn't use that order). I don't have an active support contract currently so can't check if its a know and/or fixed bug in a latter release or patch.

Comment: could you check oracle version?  I mean, result of: SELECT * from v$version;

Comment: The version is already in the answer near the top. (Oracle Database 11g Express Edition Release 11.2.0.2.0 - Production)

Answer (score 0):

The following script works as expected.

```
DROP TABLE test_tab;
CREATE TABLE test_tab ( IDNO NUMBER);
INSERT INTO test_tab VALUES (1);
INSERT INTO test_tab VALUES (2);

create or replace trigger TEST_COMP_TRIGGER
FOR UPDATE ON test_tab  
COMPOUND TRIGGER   
---- BEFORE
  BEFORE STATEMENT IS
  BEGIN
    dbms_output.put_line('TEST_COMP_TRIGGER:  BEFORE STATEMENT');
  END BEFORE STATEMENT;
---- AFTER
  AFTER STATEMENT IS
  BEGIN
    dbms_output.put_line('TEST_COMP_TRIGGER:  AFTER STATEMENT');
  END AFTER STATEMENT;
---- BEFORE EACH
  BEFORE EACH ROW IS
  BEGIN
    dbms_output.put('TEST_COMP_TRIGGER:  BEFORE EACH ROW');
    dbms_output.put(' old: ' || :old.IDNO || ' new: ' || :new.IDNO);
    :New.IDNO := :new.IDNO + 1;
    dbms_output.put_line(' old: ' || :old.IDNO || ' new: ' || :new.IDNO);
  END BEFORE EACH ROW;
---- AFTER EACH  
  AFTER EACH ROW IS
  BEGIN
    dbms_output.put('TEST_COMP_TRIGGER:  AFTER EACH ROW');
    dbms_output.put_line(' old: ' || :old.IDNO || ' new: ' || :new.IDNO);
  END AFTER EACH ROW;
END TEST_COMP_TRIGGER;
/

set serveroutput on format wraped;
UPDATE test_tab SET test_tab.IDNO=test_tab.IDNO+1;
/
```

Generates as output:

```
table TEST_TAB dropped.
table TEST_TAB created.
1 rows inserted.
1 rows inserted.
TRIGGER TEST_COMP_TRIGGER compiled
2 rows updated.
TEST_COMP_TRIGGER:  BEFORE STATEMENT
TEST_COMP_TRIGGER:  BEFORE EACH ROW old: 1 new: 2 old: 1 new: 3
TEST_COMP_TRIGGER:  AFTER EACH ROW old: 1 new: 3
TEST_COMP_TRIGGER:  BEFORE EACH ROW old: 2 new: 3 old: 2 new: 4
TEST_COMP_TRIGGER:  AFTER EACH ROW old: 2 new: 4
TEST_COMP_TRIGGER:  AFTER STATEMENT
```

Now for the fun.

- comment out the line using bind variables in AFTER EACH ROW and you get blank :NEW bind variables in BEFORE EACH ROW
- re-ordering the sections can make it work again, for example moving AFTER EACH ROW to the top of the trigger
- some orderings give blank :NEW without any lines commented out (BEFORE STATEMENT, BEFORE ROW, AFTER ROW, AFTER STATEMENT for example)

Very finicky and odd behavior.